# Mongoose save() - inside a wrapper function - return document gives depreciation warning

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My code is like this:

```
const mongoose = require('../common/mongoose.service').mongoose;

//..     
//.. schema definition here..
//.. 

//-- create the model
const Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);

//-- delete "__v" field
studentSchema.set('toJSON', {
    getters: true,
    transform: (doc, ret) => {    
      delete ret.__v;
      return ret;
    },
});

exports.createStudent = (studentData) => {
    const student = new Student(studentData);
    return student.save();
};
```

And it was giving me the `_id` when I call this `createStudent()` method from my `Student` controller.

Now I was trying to get the inserted document, updated my code like this:

```
exports.createStudent = (studentData) => {
    const student = new Student(studentData);
    return student.save().then( s => { return s } ).catch( err => console.log(err) );
};
```

Package versions:

```
"mongoose": "^5.9.23",
"mongoose-sequence": "^5.2.2",
```

My questions:

1. My Visual Studio Code editor suggests me to make this `createStudent` asynchronous. Is it needed?
2. The code that I added for deleting the "_v" field doesn't seem to be work in the above return. I mean inside the `then()` of `save()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a little bit of refactoring here. Either you directly return the promise from the method or execute it and resolve the value as promise value.

```
exports.createStudent = (studentData) => {
    const student = new Student(studentData);
    return student.save().then( s => { return s } ).catch( err => console.log(err) );
};
```

> In the above code, you have a return statement as well as then/catch,
> it turns out that while it is
> saving the user with User.save() which is asynchronous, your return doing an explicit
> return and in this case it would `undefined.

As mongoose returns promise for the save method,either you just call it like this

```
// return a promise here
exports.createStudent = (studentData) => {
  const student = new Student(studentData);
  return student.save()
};
```

Wherever you call the `createStudent()` meaning a controller/service, just use `then`  and `catch` or use `async/await`. Let assume we're calling it in the following function.

```
function execute() {
  createStudent({fname:'john', lname: 'doe'}).then(res => {
    console.log("student: ", student);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    //handle error
  })
}
```

Or simply use async await to make it even more simpler

```
async function execute() {
  try {
    let student = await createStudent({fname:'john', lname: 'doe'});
    console.log("student: ", student);

  } catch(err) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

To answer your second question, I am not sure whether we can use `userSchema.set` to override the `toJSON`, But I tried the following and it seems to be working as expected for me.

Here is a `User` model. Do note that the `toJSON` is inside the model property and I am deleting `__v` and `_id` properties here.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 30,
        trim: true
    },
    role: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    todos: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Todo"
    }]
}, {
    toJSON: {
        getters: true,
        transform: function(doc, ret) {
            delete ret._id;
            delete ret.__v
        }
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

I have a `user/` which simply fetches all the user from my DB and it returns exactly the kind of response I am looking for, no `__v` and `_id` properties in it.

[image]